# Error when dividing string by integer in python. How to ignore the error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| state | var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 | 6 | 5 | (T) |
| 2 | 46 | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 42 | 12 | (D) | 9 |

I want to write a code dividing each cell from the var2 to var4 by var1 (row by row).
While doing so, how to ignore (D) and (T) which are not integers on the dataframe?

I tried the code below but it casts an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'".

Help appreciated!

```
df.iloc[:,2:4].div(df.iloc[:,1], axis = 0)
```

Comment: maybe try converting those columns `to_numeric` first

Comment: Ignore and then what? What should `"(T)"/"(D)"` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
```